# How to output my data as CSV

Tags: python, csv, export

I'm trying to write a python script which I can use to pull in balances from Binance and export that as CSV on a regular basis. I have my API call setup to get the balances using [this](https://github.com/toshima/binance), and the output looks like the following:

```
u'ARK': {'locked': u'0.00000000', 'free': u'0.56748500'}, u'ARN': {'locked': u'0.00000000', 'free': u'0.06450000'}}.
```

What would be a good way to separate this all out and get it into a CSV?

Comment: There is a [CSV library for Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). You should be able to open the CSV file, then write to it separating everything you want by a comma, however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

# get some output as a dictionary. i got this from the link you provided
dict_to_output = {u'123456': {'ask': u'0.00000000',
  'askQty': u'0.00000000',
  'bid': u'0.00000000',
  'bidQty': u'0.00000000'},
 u'ASTBTC': {'ask': u'0.00005149',
  'askQty': u'3396.00000000',
  'bid': u'0.00004951',
  'bidQty': u'222.00000000'}}

# load the output into pandas dataframe
 df_to_output = pd.DataFrame(dict_to_output)

# output the file
 df_to_output.to_csv(r'C:\Users\fffrost\Desktop\output.csv')
```

Comment: This seems to be working pretty well! One thing that's weird though is the path in the to_csv command is ending up as the file name? Another question I would have is is there are a way to write to the next line so it doesn't overwrite the existing data after each run?